# Pressing multiple keys but need certain keys only firing once until depressed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the multiple keys method found on W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_controllers.asp).
I only need *certain keys firing once* until depressed, namely 88 and 90 (X and Z).

Code:

```
var keys = []; // Array of keys
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e) {
    e = e || event; // to deal with IE
    keys[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
}

function keyInputs() {

    if (x > 0 - (offsetXright[piece][rotation] * 20) && keys[37]) {
        x -= 20
    } //Left key

    if (x < 180 + (offsetXleft[piece][rotation] * 20) && keys[39]) {
        x += 20
    } //Right key

    if (keys[40]) {
        y += 20;
    } //Down key

    if (keys[90]) {
        rotation -= 1;
    } //Z key

    if (keys[88]) {
        rotation += 1;
    } //X key 
}
```

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask? Could you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your keyDown handler is firing as long as you keep the key pressed.
I'd recommend adding a global variable **released**, which gets set to true as soon either z or x are, well, released.
Now you can simply check if e.g. **z** is pressed AND if **released==true** - if so, rotate your object and set released to false.

Here's a sample:

```js
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 300;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var player = {
      xPos: 110,
      yPos: 110,
      rotation: 0,
      width: 24,
      height: 24
    };
    var keys = [];
    var released = true;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      keys = (keys || []);
      keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = false;
      if (e.keyCode == 88 || e.keyCode == 90) {
        released = true;
      }
    });


    function loop() {
      if (keys[37]) {
        player.xPos -= 10;
      }
      if (keys[39]) {
        player.xPos += 10;
      }
      if (keys[90] && released) {
        player.rotation--;
        released = false;
      }
      if (keys[88] && released) {
        player.rotation++;
        released = false;
      }
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.fillStyle = "red";
      context.save();
      context.rotate(player.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
      context.fillRect(player.xPos, player.yPos, player.width, player.height);
      context.restore();
    }
    var interval = setInterval(loop, 20);
```